# Can a factor levels be 0

Tags: r, levels

I thought I perfectly understood the factor class in R, but finally, I may  not.
I can't find a way to transform a vector of 0/1 into a factor without transforming the original value in 1/2.
Here is a minimal working example:

```
foo<-c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,NA,0,1)
bar<-factor(foo)
str(bar)
```

results in:

> Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 NA 1 2

and

```
bar<-factor(foo, labels = c("(0) No", "(1) Yes"))
str(bar)
```

results in:

> Factor w/ 2 levels "(0) No","(1) Yes": 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 NA 1 2

and

```
bar<-factor(foo, levels= c(0,1), labels = c("(0) No", "(1) Yes"))
str(bar)
```

results in:

> Factor w/ 2 levels "(0) No","(1) Yes": 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 NA 1 2

Is it because R can have a level equal to 0?

I really want to keep the original values as 0/1 to facilitate data sharing, but could someone provide a solution?

Comment: The original values are the ones you had before. The 1/2 thing you see in `str` is the position of the value. That's why it will always include 1. It will help you understand the connection between value and position/number if in each case you run `str(bar); bar;  as.character(bar); as.numeric(bar)`

Comment: What do you expect `levels = c(0,1)` to do? Change it so that `as.numeric(bar)` returns a vector of values in `0,1` rather than `1,2`?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you want a factor? What is wrong with integer 0 and 1?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 0 and 1, indeed it is how I prefer it. However, I have to perform statistical analysis (which is not a problem) but also to provide a clean data file for other researchers who would like to work on it. Hence, I have to follow adapt my workflow to the local habits